# Graphql multiple queries and mutation using Graphene

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python, graphql-python

I chose to handle sending multiple Queries and Mutations as follow,

First I defined a `Schema` defined in schema.py:

```
# schema.py code
from graphene import Schema, Field, ObjectType
from .basic_objects.queries import BasicQuery
from .basic_objects.mutations import BasicMutation

schema = Schema(query=BasicQuery, mutation=BasicMutation)
```

Then I have updated the `schema.py` file:

```
from graphene import Schema, Field, ObjectType
from .basic_objects.queries import BasicQuery
from .basic_objects.mutations import BasicMutation


class Query(ObjectType):
    BasicQuery = Field(BasicQuery)
    #otherQuery

class Mutation(ObjectType):
    BasicMutation = Field(BasicMutation)


schema = Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

But while trying to send the following GraphQL request:

```
query MyQuery {
  BasicQueryData {
    oneNode(id: 1) {
      comment
      coordinateY
    }
  }
}
```

from query oneNode directly working and graphene find the method and it is working.

**How can I make that this time from query first go to BasicQueryData and then call oneNode method?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Query(BasicQuery):
    Field(BasicQuery)


class Mutation(BasicMutation):
    Field(BasicMutation)


schema = Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

I fixed like this